# How to exchange facebook code for an access_token

Tags: java, spring, facebook, authentication, oauth-2.0

I start `oAuth2` with Facebook from client side and I get code after successful user login. Now I want exchange code for an **access_token** like here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/manually-build-a-login-flow

How can I exchange code for token? I need do `REST GET` Request with `WebClient` or do simple redirect with `Spring` Controller? I want to do this without any external library.

My flow I think should look like:

1. User clicks `Login with Facebook`
2. Redirected with code to backend
3. Gets code and exchanges for a **access_token**
4. Call **Graph QL** for user data
5. Save user data, generate **JWT** and back to frontend.

Comment: No, not a redirect - that would make the request happen on the client side. But it must be made from the server side. (It contains your app secret, and that must never be exposed in publicly available client-side code to begin with.)

Answer (score 0):

From the question I understand you need to basically implement [Authorization code](https://www.oauth.com/oauth2-servers/server-side-apps/authorization-code/) flow of the OAuth2.0 protocol.

After you receive code, you have to exchange it for a token. For this you would have to send a POST request(through your spring controller) to access token endpoint of Facebook. With this you would have to send additional details like client_id, client_secret which you have received when you created a fakebook client application.

PS:I understand you might have constraints with using third party libaries to achive this, but have a look at this awsome [open-source](https://github.com/3pillarlabs/socialauth/) library.

Comment: I solved my problem. I called wrong Facebook API URL. I do copy paste in my configuration.

Comment: @tomDev93 could you tell what link you're using?